# isc-dhcp-server not 'listening;

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

I have got isc-dhcp-server set up on my Raspberry Pi (acting as a router), but when a client attempts a request, the Raspberry Pi does not pick it up.

However, when I run:

```
nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover -v -e eth0
```

It gets a DHCPOFFER.
Why do the DHCP requests not 'get through' the Ethernet interface.

I'm on a raspberry pi 1B (Old, I know.)

Comment: Run `sudo ss -ltn4` and see if the service is listening on port 69. Also have you verified it's running and there are no syntax errors?

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when I get the chance.